# Trying to input line of integer and sorts in insertion sort type of function with vector as storage

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> var;
    int numb,i;
    char temp;

    cout<<"Enter numbers: ";
    //Inputs integers with spaces
    while(cin>>numb>>temp){
        var[i]=numb;
        i++;
        if(temp==char(13)){
            break;
        }
    }
    insertionSort(var);
    for(int a=0;a<i;a++){
        cout<<var[a]<<" ";
    }
```

This program terminates after enter key has been pressed, any idea how to fix it?

EDIT:

Updated version of the program and while loop wont terminate after pressing enter key

```
    vector<int> var;
    int numb,i=0;
    cout<<"Enter numbers: ";
    while(cin>>numb){
        if(numb==char(13)){
        break;
        }
        else{
        var.push_back(numb);
    }
    }
    insertionSort(var);
    for(int a=0;a<i;a++){
        cout<<var[a]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized `i` so `var[i]=numb;` could be anything and you have undefined behavior.  You also never initialized `var` so `var[i]=numb;` could be anything and you have undefined behavior.

Also with `cin>>numb>>temp` is not going to consume the white space between the numbers.  `cin` already ignores white space so this is trimming some of the numbers you entered.

EDIT:

Your new code forgets to increment `i` while you are getting the input.  Instead of doing that though you can just use the `size()` function of the vector and change your for loop to

```
for(size_t a=0; a < var.size(); ++a){
    cout<<var[a]<<" ";
}
```

Or better yet use a [ranged based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) like

```
for (auto e : var)
    std::cout << e << " ";
```

Comment: Changed var[i]=numb; to var.push_back(numb): and now I cant terminate the loop with enter and changed cin>>numb>>temp to cin>>numb

Comment: @Testermoon01 I updated the answer to show why you do not get output.

Comment: You're right, my last problem is while loop still wont terminate on pressing enter instead terminates when I pressed different key. I need that enter key to terminate it. Any ideas?

Comment: @Testermoon01 Not sure what is going on.  [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/785de7a041368f9d) works perfectly for me and after I press `Ctrl+z` all I have to do is press enter.

Comment: Is there an alternate for Ctrl+Z? Because I should need enter key to terminate the looop

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually read spaces, `cin` will just ignore that space for you.

So you just need:

```
while(cin>>numb)
```

Also `char(13)` is the carriage return in ascii. So you don't need these two lines either:

```
if(temp==char(13))
    break;
```

Instead, users will signal `EOF` to break the loop. In Linux, it's `Ctrl+D`; in Windows, it's `Ctrl+Z`.

Besides, other answers have said that you should use `push_back`.

The code is just this simple:

```
while (cin >> numb)
    var.push_back(numb);
```

**EDIT**:

Your updated code is also problematic. You never updated `i` but used to it print out the array. Here's the full working version.

```
while (cin >> numb)
    var.push_back(numb);

insertionSort(var);

for (int i = 0; i < var.size(); i++)
    cout << var[i] << endl;
```

Comment: I added push_back instead of giving value to var[i] and now I cant stop the  while loop from inputting values

Comment: See my edits on the `EOF` and hit return afterwards.

Comment: Tried Ctrl+Z and didnt do anything. If it helps, Im using devc++ and still I cant terminate the while loop with the push_back and why wouldn't I need the if statement? Im just a student though.

Comment: Did you remember to hit the `Enter` key? I understand that.

Comment: Of course.It just moves the pointer down and entering values is infinite

Comment: @Testermoon01 When you enter `Ctrl+Z` do you see `^Z` in the command prompt?

Comment: Yes sir, and I entered it. Then my for loop for displaying the values in var didnt kick in

Comment: @Testermoon01 What does your code look like now that you made the changes?  It could be that the for loop no longer runs.

Comment: Could I send you the whole code? I've been working on it in earlier this evening and I cant make the program run properly

Comment: @Testermoon01 No.  You can either update this qiestion(do not invalidate the answers you already have) or ask a new question.

Comment: @Testermoon01: I said the condition `temp == char(13)` is not needed.

Comment: I need to terminate the while loop when the user feels like. What should I do?

Comment: I also said the user will signal `EOF` to break the loop. Please read the answer carefully.

Comment: I read it but is there any alternative for Ctrl+Z ? Because I really need the enter key to terminate the program..